# ActiveReports WebViewer Looks great in Dev, bad in Staging

Tags: activereports

I have an ActiveReports WebViewer working great in my development environment. I deployed it to a staging server (Windows 2008 R2 which is IIS7) and I don't get errors, but the viewer looks all crazy. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been playing around with HTTP handlers and nothing changes the way it looks. The left pane of the viewer, which can be printing options or report parameters is stretched across the top and the images are broken. Also, the report area that normally displays the report is shrunken up and the report doesn't show. I don't have a high enough rep to post the screen shot, so I hope I have described it enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was actually a css issue. I am generating the webviewer using JavaScript, like in the Mobile example provided by component one, though I extended it to do things a little differently. I hadn't copied over the css file! Whoops!

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that the Web.config on the staging server matches your Web.config on your dev machine ie, please make sure that the Version attribute on each assembly matches the version of your DLLs

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFrameork="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Extensibility.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Diagnostics.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Chart.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Html.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Image.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
      <add assembly="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Web.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Next, ensure that the DLLs are being published to the bin folder on the staging server as well.

Regards,
Mohita

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the assembly references to GrapeCity.ActiveReports are set to Copy Local true.